# Setting homepage for React-Admin app based on permissions

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-admin

I want to set the home page for a React-Admin app based on the user’s permissions, rather than [the default](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#dashboard), which is the list page of the `<Resource>` listed first in the `<Admin>` component.

My current Dashboard component actually already does this:

```
import { usePermissions, useRedirect } from 'react-admin';
import AdminDashboard from './AdminDashboard';

const Dashboard = () => {
  const { isLoading, permissions } = usePermissions();
  const redirect = useRedirect();

  if (isLoading) return null;

  switch (permissions) {
    case 'REGULAR':
      redirect('/items');
      break;
    case 'ADMIN':
      return <AdminDashboard />;
    default:
      return null;
  }
};

export default Dashboard;
```

But the problem is the redirect gives a warning: `Warning: Cannot update a component ('HistoryRouter') while rendering a different component ('AppDashboard')...`

I’d just like to resolve this annoying warning, while still achieving what my code already does:

- set the home page for one user type to the list page of a `<Resource>` that's *not* listed first
- set the home page for another type to a dashboard component (`<AdminDashboard>` above)

I tried swapping *useRedirect* with React Router's *useNavigate* and get the same warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to resolve this by using React-Router's Navigate component:

```
import { usePermissions } from 'react-admin';
import AdminDashboard from './AdminDashboard';

const Dashboard = () => {
  const { isLoading, permissions } = usePermissions();

  if (isLoading) return null;

  switch (permissions) {
    case 'REGULAR':
      return <Navigate replace to="/tveclasses" />
    case 'ADMIN':
      return <AdminDashboard />;
    default:
      return null;
  }
};

export default Dashboard;
```

The warning is gone and all seems to work as intended.